# Problem enabling siding generator addon

Tags: add-on, path

I created this siding generator and I have been adding some new features and I have encountered some problems that I just can't seem to get around. Currently it is not installing into Blender 2.72 properly, it works fine from the text editor, but if you try and install it as an [addon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35OsPAJ46kvM3R3b01BcThlRUU/view?usp=sharing) you get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 299, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\add_mesh_siding\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from add_mesh_siding_utils import *
ImportError: No module named 'add_mesh_siding_utils'
```

Even though the other file is right there as well. I don't get what changed, it used to work just fine.

Comment: Maybe from .add_mesh_siding_utils import * will do the job. Mind the dot before the module you want to import

Comment: Here's a thread that was just started by a person who wants to colloborate on repairing Addons that break from API changes.  A thread like this could easily become a running dialogue on how to fix many Addons and also how to avoid problems in the future.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?351179-Official-Addons-Repair-Project-for-Blender-2-73

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had this exact problem with other addons, namely the add mesh rocks, and cg cookies' poly strips.

The problem comes from the name of the directory you created in the addon folder. For your case the folder needs to be named exactly `add_mesh_siding_utils`. If you rename the folder the addon will work.
This is why, blender is trying to import everything from the addon (this line in the error message.) 
`from add_mesh_siding_utils import *`

Blender is looking for a directory called `add_mesh_siding_utils`; the directory name is the module name.