# Error Enabling Blender Addon

Tags: add-on, path

I wanted to check out an interesting addon I found on the web. So I copied the script and saved it where it should be, but then when I tried enabling it in Blender it gave me This error. (*the addon is Asset Flinger*)

[image: error message]

[image: error message]

Comment: this is the same error as described [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24054/2217). you need a new folder named "*add_mesh_asset_flinger*", then move the init.py in it.