# Cannot import name 'common_utilities'

Tags: add-on, import

I'm trying to enable my polystrips addon but I receive this error every time I try to check the enable addon box.[image]

Comment: Looks like you are having the same type of problem as I answered [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24054/2217)

Comment: I renamed my folder common_utilities and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: have you posted on the support page for the product you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to grab the code from here https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-lib and put the source files (ie `__init__.py, common_utilities.py, common_drawing.py, common_classes.py`)  into the empty retopology-polystrips-master/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, these kinds of errors have been solved by disabling any old versions of the addon, deleting them from your addons directory, re-installing the addon, saving user preferences and re-starting blender.

best,
Patrick

Comment: sheesh, a down vote.  Many people have had the cannot import errors due to stale updates of the addon.  And since OP offered no input as to whether they have tried it, the down-vote feels a little harsh.