# hardops addon in blender 2.69 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: add-on

enabled hardops 007 addon just fine when my imac was running osx Yosemite 
i try to install it now here on ubuntu and i keep getting these errors... all of my other plugins work just fine.

why ubuntu why!!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update blender.

Comment: Looks like it might be the same problem as I [answered here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24054/2217).

Comment: Can't confirm, works with 2.76+.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved. simple updated needed. just make sure hardops 007 is updated with blender 2.77 should work fine no special thing needed here.